# Lisp Unit Test Error with the FiveAM library: unable to import functions

Tags: testing, lisp, common-lisp

I am currently working on a Common Lisp project and facing an issue with unit testing. I have a file named `lec_2.lisp` containing a function `COUNT-VC-DO` that counts the vowels and consonants in a given string. However, when I run my unit tests, I encounter an error stating that the `COUNT-VC-DO` function is undefined. I have confirmed that the file path is correct and the function is defined in the file. I am using the `FiveAM` library for unit testing with quicklisp.

Directory Tree:

```
src/
├── lec_2.lisp
└── tests/
     └── test_lec_2.lisp
```

Here's the function definition from `lec_2.lisp`:

```lisp
(defun count-vc-do (s)
    ; Initialize loop variables i, accv, and accc
    (do ((i 0 (1+ i))
         (accv 0)
         (accc 0))
        ; Terminate loop when i reaches the length of s
        ((equal i (length s)) 
         (values accv accc)) ; Return the values of accv and accc
        ; Check if the current character is a vowel
        (if (vowelp (aref s i))
            ; Increment accv if the character is a vowel
            (incf accv)
            ; Check if the current character is a consonant
            (if (consonantp (aref s i))
                ; Increment accc if the character is a consonant
                (incf accc)))))
```

Here's the unit test that's failing:

```lisp
;; Load the FiveAM library
(asdf:test-system "fiveam")

;; Load the file with the functions that need testing
(load "/src/lec_2.lisp")  ; Replace with the actual file path

;; Define a test suite
(defpackage :my-tests
  (:use :cl :fiveam))

(in-package :my-tests)

(test count-vc-do-test
    (is (= (count-vc-do "example") '(3 4)))) ; 3 vowels and 4 consonants in "example"

(run! 'count-vc-do-test)
```

And here's the error message I'm receiving:

```
| Running test COUNT-VC-DO-TEST X
| Did 1 check.
|    Pass: 0 ( 0%)
|    Skip: 0 ( 0%)
|    Fail: 1 (100%)
|
| Failure Details:
| --------------------------------
| COUNT-VC-DO-TEST [A test for the count-vc-do function.]:
|      Unexpected Error: #<UNDEFINED-FUNCTION COUNT-VC-DO {1002E45DE3}>
| The function COUNT-VC-DO is undefined..
| --------------------------------
```

I've already tried reloading the file and ensuring there are no typos in the function name or the test. The file is loaded correctly, and I can call the function in the REPL without any issues. However, the unit test still fails with the same error.

Comment: This is probably related to packages: in which package is COUNT-VC-DO defined? Is the symbol exported from that package ? assuming the package is P and it is exported, you can refer to the function in your test by writing `P:COUNT-VC-DO`, or you can add a `(:use :p)` clause in the defpackage of your test package

Comment: I am confused about how to apply it could be applied. Could you provide the full code for it, please? I am kind of new to lisp

Answer (score 3):

In your test, try to call `cl-user::count-vc-do`.

If you showed us the full content of your file `lec_2.lisp`, that contains the function definition, then this function is created in the CL-USER package, the default one.

But in your test file, you create a package -which is good, it helps for encapsulation.

```lisp
;; here the current package is CL-USER

(defpackage :my-tests
  (:use :cl :fiveam)) ;; <-- you create a package: good idea.

(in-package :my-tests) 

;; now the current package is this one and not CL-USER

(test count-vc-do-test
    (is (= (count-vc-do "example") '(3 4))))
;;          ^^^^
;;          Your Lisp is looking for this function in the my-tests package
;;          and it, rightly, doesn't exist.
```

either refer to the function with a package prefix (cl-user), with a double colon (::) because your function is not `export`-ed,

either create a package in your first file, and two choices again:

- export the function and `use` this package like you do for fiveam
- or also use the package prefix (with or without exporting the function).

Functions that you don't export won't be "imported" with `:use`, but you can refer to them anyways with the :: notation.

---

https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/packages.html